# Custom MBean SNMP publishing on WebLogic 10.3.

Tags: weblogic, jmx, snmp, weblogic-10.x, mbeans

I'm currently experiencing an issue with the custom mbean SNMP publishing  function that WebLogic 10.3 provides.
Basically, the problem is that certain attributes, which are all different numeric primitive types (long and double) are all coming null when I do the SNMP request to the agent, however, the String ones, are coming nicely. Here's an example:

```
OID:       
1.3.6.1.4.1.140.625.50.1.109.111.110.105.116.111.114.2.1.1.3.16.21.18.124.43.0.250.193.169.164.9.128.13.10.219.116.151 
Value: 

OID:
1.3.6.1.4.1.140.625.50.1.109.111.110.105.116.111.114.2.1.1.2.16.21.18.124.43.0.250.193.169.164.9.128.13.10.219.116.151 
Value: com.test.application:Location=app,MyTestBean=Name
```

I've tested this in WebLogic 12.1c and it's working flawlessly, and I can confirm that the MBean is being properly published on WL10, as all the MBean attributes are appearing successfully if I query for them directly.

Let me know if you need further information or have any questions.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been able to have this one solved by disabling the MBeans publishing feature on the SNMP Agent and enabling it back, that caused the MIB tables to be reset as apparently there were some key constraints when trying to insert the values of the MBeans.

Thanks!

Regards.

Comment: HI LdSe, can you pls tell me where you found this option for enabling/disabling publishing MBeans?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, it's under Diagnostics -> SNMP -> Select an Agent and under the "General" tab, you'll find "Access For User MBeans Enabled". Let me know if it worked for you. Regards.

Comment: Hello, tnx for help, but this doesn't help me. From where you get oids for custom MBeans? TNX

Comment: Tnx for try to help. Just to let you know finally I got it to work. Issue was how spring generates MBeans.